# Case sensitive in search result with RegExp in razor MVC RSS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code for displaying result from search.

```
@foreach (var str in (item.ContentText.Split(new char[] { '?', '<', '!', '<', '^', '>', '*', '>'}).Where(a => a.Contains((string)ViewData["searchTerm"]))))
{
                        @Html.Raw(Regex.Replace(str, (string)ViewData["searchTerm"],
 "<span style='background-color:rgb(245, 234, 157); color:rgb(243, 122, 122)'>" + (string)ViewData["searchTerm"] + "</span>"))
}
                    </a>
```

Is there any reg exp in razor for ignore case sensitive?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(str, (string)ViewData["searchTerm"], ..., RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` => is this what you want? You can use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` to make pattern matching case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to add is [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) as the last argument of [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f(v=vs.110).aspx) overload:

```
@foreach (var str in (item.ContentText.Split(new char[] { '?', '<', '!', '<', '^', '>', '*', '>'}).Where(a => a.Contains((string)ViewData["searchTerm"]))))
{
     @Html.Raw(Regex.Replace(str, (string)ViewData["searchTerm"],
               "<span style='background-color:rgb(245, 234, 157); color:rgb(243, 122, 122)'>" + (string)ViewData["searchTerm"] + "</span>",
               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
}
```

The default setting for `Regex.Replace` is [`RegexOptions.None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.none), which includes following rules (with emphasis about case sensitivity):

> - The pattern is interpreted as a canonical rather than an ECMAScript    regular expression.
> - The regular expression pattern is matched in the input string from    left to right.
> - **Comparisons are case-sensitive.**
> - The `^` and `$` language elements match the beginning and end of the    input string.
> - The `.` language element matches every character except `\n`.
> - Any white space in a regular expression pattern is interpreted as a    literal space character.
> - The conventions of the current culture are used when comparing the    pattern to the input string.
> - Capturing groups in the regular expression pattern are implicit as    well as explicit.

**Note:** All regex options provided by `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace instead of Razor engine itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` , i think it will work for you.

Comment: Provide a example or solution code to make your answer look more understandable by others who might be facing the same problem.